# Confusion about the tie-break in the Grenke Chess Classics 2015

Tags: tournament, carlsen

I am confused about the result of the Grenke Chess Classics 2015.

At the one hand, Magnus Carlsen won 3 games and Arkadij Naiditsch only 2, so due to
 the tiebreaker-rule, Carlsen should have won the tournament.

But then I noticed that 5 tie break games were added.

What is true and who won the tournament ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carlsen won the tie-break (and the tournament).

Quite dramatically, after trading wins in the rapid and draws in the blitz games, with a win in the armageddon game.

The tie-break rules were only used to sort out the places apart from the first place.

http://www.grenkechessclassic.de/en/grenke-chess-classic-2015/rules-regulations

http://en.chessbase.com/post/grenke-final-carlsen-wins-in-armageddon